# Multiple Database Configs in C Language

Tags: c, database, config, environment

We need to develop a database api which will be used on embedded systems. This api will have different database configs which contain different
database environment settings( like Sqlite, MySQL or file system ). In this context, I've explored it but could not find anything applicable. 
Is there any approach in C language which contains multiple database settings like C# or other languages ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: ODBC is about the nearest you'll find to a lingua franca for C programs communicating with SQL DBMS.

Comment: Is it possible to make different database setting for different database environments with ODBC ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean.  Classically, ODBC drivers are configured via an `odbc.ini` file or some similar name, when not configured via the Windows registry.  You can select which ODBC connection you use; the corresponding settings will be used.